# Captive portal : external splash page specs?

Tags: wireless-networking, authentication, ios, captive-portal

Captive portals - like in restaurants, hostels, airports, ... - are detected by OSes. When detected, OS displays a browser-like windows (~popup). (Generally in order to ask for authentification, login, credits, or simply displaying conditions or warning).

I simply wonder what are the specification of such a "splash page". Example : iOS detects a captive portal, allright, it looks for the splash page, but where does iOS find it ?

Comment: e.g. for a specific tool : http://help.tanaza.com/customer/portal/articles/987526-captive-portal-and-splash-page

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal explains it well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specs anywhere.
I phoned Apple and got nothing more.

I decompiled CNA.app and got nothing interesting.

I digged the Console and got some infos.

Absolutely opaque.